# Difference between usage of const in variable and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I would like to know if there is any difference in the usage of `const` between variable and pointer, like in the following:

```
const int var;
const int *ptr;
```

Comment: `var = 42;` is illegal ... `ptr = &var;` is legal... `*ptr = 42;` is illegal

Comment: The first one says that you can't change `var`, the second one says that you can't change the data that `ptr` points to.

Comment: For more fun: [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Like in pointers is there any difference between const int var, and int const var ?

Comment: @poorna No, there is not.